# how to analyze text in elasticsearch using java api?

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I use Elasticsearch 1.7.4 and its Java API. Currently, I want to count the top 10 high frequency searching words by user. So I have to record the words of query text which user type to search, and before recording the words I have to analyze the query text. I find the restful way to analyze text as the [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-analyze.html) says, but I can't find the api in TransportClient.

do anyone know how to analyze text in elasticsearch using Java api or some other way rather than requesting the restful api?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the example from the documentation (where the text "this is a test" is being analyzed using the `standard` analyzer), here is an example of how one might accomplish the same analysis using the Java API:

```
TransportClient client = new TransportClient();
AnalyzeRequest request = (new AnalyzeRequest("this is a test")).analyzer("standard");
List<AnalyzeResponse.AnalyzeToken> tokens = client.admin().indices().analyze(request).actionGet().getTokens();
for (AnalyzeResponse.AnalyzeToken token : tokens)
{
    // do something with each token...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes!!! This is exactly what I want! Thank u so much! By the way,may I ask how do you find this JAVA API ? cuz I can't figure out an easy way to find the Java API which I want.

Comment: @abu I usually just browse the source code directly for the Java API. I downloaded the source and attached it to Netbeans, which is what I use to develop. But, I have also browsed the javadocs online before. You can find them here: http://javadoc.kyubu.de/elasticsearch/v1.7.3/

Comment: ,thanks a lot. I am new to Elasticsearch and I will learn it by your way.

Comment: You're welcome @abu glad I could help. Have fun with ES!