# Call search_analyzer on text using elasticsearch java api

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I have the same question as this post but with one difference.  I need to analyze text using the elasticsearch api, but calling the **search_analyzer** for the field.

(previous answer) [how to analyze text in elasticsearch using java api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040625/how-to-analyze-text-in-elasticsearch-using-java-api)

The field that I care about has both an analyzer and a custom analyzer.  Like so:

> ```
>        "body": {
>           "type": "string",
>           "fields": {"exact":{"type":"string"}},
>          "analyzer" : "customfullTextUAX",
>          "search_analyzer" : "customfullText"
>        }
> ```
>
> ...

The code i have been calling to analyze it uses the analyzer, and i cannot figure out any setting which would call the search_analyzer.

Code I used:

```
AnalyzeRequest ac = new AnalyzeRequest(index).field(field).text(text).explain(true);
DetailAnalyzeResponse dar = iac.analyze(ac).actionGet().detail();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly instruct the `AnalyzeRequest` to use the search analyzer instead:

```
AnalyzeRequest ac = new AnalyzeRequest(index)
    .field(field)
    .analyzer("customfullText")          <--- add this
    .text(text)
    .explain(true);
DetailAnalyzeResponse dar = iac.analyze(ac).actionGet().detail();
```

Comment: Thanks, thats about what I was thinking.

Comment: Do you know, is there an easier way to find the analyzer name customfullText?

Comment: (having trouble with the interface, sorry)
The only way I know how is to get the mappings source, deserialize it to a map, and iterate over every type until i find the field i'm looking for.
It just seems like a significant chunk of work that I don't have to do when using the index analyzer.

Comment: Because the index analyzer is the one used by default when analyzing a field. You would like to be able to call `AnalyzeRequest.useSearchAnalyzer()` but that doesn't exist unfortunately.

Comment: One more comment.
I tried this and ran into the difficulty.  It seems if field is set it will ignore the specified analyzer.  So my solution was to remove the field if the analyzer name was provided.
Once I did that it worked great.