# Using Elasticsearch Java API to analyze text

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using Elastic's Java library 6.2.4 and I'm trying to analyze text. I couldn't find any mention of how to do it in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.2/java-rest-high-supported-apis.html) and I couldn't find any mention of it the 6.3 version of the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.3/java-rest-high.html). I tried to build an `AnalyzerRequest` as seen bellow

```
 try(RestHighLevelClient client = 
     new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(elasticsearchHost, elasticsearchPort, elasticsearchScheme)))) {

     AnalyzeRequest analyzeRequest = new AnalyzeRequest()
                                   .index(elasticsearchIndex)
                                   .analyzer("my_analyzer")
                                   .text("Some Text To Analyze);
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Could not connect to elasticsearch", e);
}
```

But I couldn't find how to use it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35042859/4890123) answer suggests using the `TransportClient` which is deprecated so I can't use it and I couldn't find other examples.

When I tried to look into what `RestHighLevelClient` offered I only found methods for searching, indexing, etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`analyze` method is in process and targeted for version 6.4: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/31577

You can use [PreBuiltTransportClient](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/transport/6.3.0/org/elasticsearch/transport/client/PreBuiltTransportClient.html):

```
Settings settings = ....;
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
AnalyzeRequest analyzeRequest = ...;
ActionFuture<AnalyzeResponse> analyzeResponse = client.admin().indices().analyze(analyzeRequest);
```

Or you can use Low Level Client and make a custom rest request: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.2/java-rest-low-usage-requests.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-analyze.html